# How do I solve this ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, alert

Here is the problem:

> Declare a variable called `x` and assign it a value that equals the remainder of 20 divided by 3. Next, divide and assign 1 to that variable and display the result in an alert box. The result should be 2.

Here is my code:

```
var x = 20 / 3;
alert(x / 1);
```

I am brand new to Javascript. I am coming up with 6.66. The answer should be 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 20 / 3 is 6.6* why it should be 2?

Comment: I concur, 20/3 is 6.666... Input this equation into a calculator, you'll see that the answer is what you've been getting all along. I'm not sure where you get 2 from.

Comment: @aliusman Remainder, not just division

Comment: ah, that's right, @Feathercrown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need this:

> the ***remainder*** of 20 divided by 3

You're ***dividing***. The remainder (or modulo) operator in JavaScript is the percentage symbol (`%`).

So your code should look like this instead:

```js
var x = 20 % 3;
alert(x / 1);
```

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp

Comment: @codingcali If this is the answer that worked for you, you can click the checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is `%` in `JS` for remainder. `/` is the division sign.

```js
var x = 20 % 3; console.log(x / 1);
```